# How do I create a Like button for specific web pages within one company

Tags: facebook, plugins

First let me apologize for my lack of knowledge - I'm not a programmer.  I'm a staff member of a small non profit that's trying to tackle social media.

We have a FB Like button that we put on our website that directs people to our company FB page.

However I'm trying to create a Like button for specific webpages.  For example, we sell webinars and we create a specific webpage for each webinar with the description etc.  How can I put a like button on that webpage, so that when people click it, it appears on their personal FB wall that they like this specific webinar?

I've seen this done for articles that I've read, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this for our company.

I'd appreciate any advice you can give - in layman's terms please.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would use the iframe version of the like button, "does not include send button".
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Simply add the url to the page you are installing your button in the Like Button code wizard then uncheck send button, when the code window pops up, select iframe.

The wizard will generate the iframe code you need and encode the url to your page for the iframe, sample below.  This can be done with Facebook Page Profile URL's and External Website URL's.

---

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fanotherfeed.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=148744491883305" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```